# Programmatically using constraints - anchors vs VFL (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to learn how to incorporate constraints programmatically.

Given three container views, I would like my display to look something like the following when switching from portrait to landscape. (The heights of the orange and yellow views equal the height of the blue in both portrait and landscape, the yellow view remains the same height, the widths of both sides are equal in landscape, and the margins remain the same in both portrait and landscape.)

Can I do this using only anchor constraints?  What about using Visual Format Language?

Suppose I want the blue view to take up one third of the screen?

Other than the code using anchors being easier to read than VFL, is one method better than the other?

[image]

[image]

Comment: use size classes ...

Comment: @ jawadAli: what does that mean?

Comment: Thanks to DonMag who posted an answer here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362538/programmatic-constraints-with-screen-rotation-swift

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchors or VFL, it doesn't matter since they are just different ways to construct constraints. But I personally prefer anchors since they are type-safe, easy to write, and shorter when compared to VFL. And yes, you can use size classes to let the system decide when you should change your UI to landscape (regular) or portrait (compact). Without size classes, you still can do it by just update your UI to adapt to the current device orientation. Choosing which one depends on your need.