# Programmatic constraints with screen rotation (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 UIViews, cv1 and cv2.  When in portrait, I want cv1 to occupy the top half of the screen and cv2 the bottom half.  When rotated into landscape, I want cv1 to take the left half and cv2 to take the right half, like this:

[image]
[image]

Here is how I have it set up (the `ChildView1` and `ChildView2` classes only provide the colors and corner rounding):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let cv1 = ChildView1()
    let cv2 = ChildView2()
        
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        var safeAreaHeight: CGFloat {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                return view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size.height
            }
            return view.bounds.height
        }
        //debugPrint("height = \(safeAreaHeight)")

        var safeAreaWidth: CGFloat {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                return view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.size.width
            }
            return view.bounds.width
        }
        //debugPrint("width = \(safeAreaWidth)")


        cv1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        cv1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            
        if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portrait || UIDevice.current.orientation == .portraitUpsideDown {

            cv1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: safeAreaHeight / 2).isActive = true
            cv1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: safeAreaWidth).isActive = true

            cv2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            cv2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            
            //debugPrint("Portrait: height = \(safeAreaHeight), width = \(safeAreaWidth)")

        } else if UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeLeft || UIDevice.current.orientation == .landscapeRight {
            
            cv1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: safeAreaHeight).isActive = true
            cv1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: safeAreaWidth / 2).isActive = true
            
            cv2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            cv2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

            //debugPrint("Landscape: height = \(safeAreaHeight), width = \(safeAreaWidth)")
        }

        cv2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        cv2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.widthAnchor).isActive = true            
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        addCV1()
        addCV2()
    }
    
    func addCV1() {
        self.view.addSubview(cv1)
        cv1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
    
    func addCV2() {
        self.view.addSubview(cv2)
        cv2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    
}
```

If I begin in either portrait or landscape, it looks fine.  But when I rotate the screen both view disappear and I get the following error message for each constraint:

```
2020-08-11 10:28:55.328063-0600 RotateScreenTesting[91471:4449618] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
"Portrait: height = 603.0, width = 375.0"
2020-08-11 10:29:15.046153-0600 RotateScreenTesting[91471:4449618] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d74500 RotateScreenTesting.ChildView1:0x7fceba30a720.height == 301.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d6d180 RotateScreenTesting.ChildView1:0x7fceba30a720.height == 343   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600003d6d180 RotateScreenTesting.ChildView1:0x7fceba30a720.height == 343   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
(lldb)
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: before update constraint you have to clear old one first.

Comment: You're doing a number of things wrong, but first... What do you consider "portrait orientation"? If the app is on an iPad and the user is multitasking with SplitView / SlideOver, the device may be in "landscape" orientation, but your app may be tall and narrow.

Comment: @DonMag: So far I've only been doing this for the iPhone, filing away ideas for the iPad for later...  What things am I doing wrong?  (I am pretty new to this...)

Comment: @Niraj Solanki: I originally tried to do that by setting       cv1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true, then back to false again - but that didn't work.  You may have the solution below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to remember that we should be working with ***size*** layouts, rather than portrait / landscape. With multitasking slide over / split views, it's not unusual to have your view have a different height:width ratio than the device itself.

There are various ways to handle this... here's one approach.

- create an array of "wide layout" constraints
- create an array of "narrow layout" constraints
- create an array of "common" constraints - these apply whether in narrow or wide "orientation"
- activate  / deactivate the wide and narrow constraints, based on the size of the view

Try this example:

```
class ChildView1: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        backgroundColor = .blue
        layer.cornerRadius = 16
    }
}

class ChildView2: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        backgroundColor = .red
        layer.cornerRadius = 16
    }
}

class SampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let cv1 = ChildView1()
    let cv2 = ChildView2()
    
    // array of constraints for "wide" layout
    var wideConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    // array of constraints for "narrow" layout
    var narrowConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    
    // just for clarity, array of constraints that apply for
    //  both wide and narrow layouts
    var commonConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        cv1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cv2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(cv1)
        view.addSubview(cv2)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        commonConstraints = [
            // cv1 will always be constrained top and leading
            cv1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            cv1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            
            // cv2 will always be constrained trailing and bottom
            cv2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            cv2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ]

        // when narrow, cv1 on top of cv2
        narrowConstraints = [
            // constrain cv1 trailing
            cv1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            // constrain cv2 leading
            cv2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            // constrain cv2 top to cv1 bottom
            cv2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.bottomAnchor),
            // make them equal heights
            cv2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.heightAnchor),
        ]
        
        // when wide, cv1 side-by-side cv2
        wideConstraints = [
            // constrain cv1 bottom
            cv1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            // constrain cv2 top
            cv2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            // constrain cv2 leading to cv1 trailing
            cv2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.trailingAnchor),
            // make them equal widths
            cv2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cv1.widthAnchor),
        ]
        
        // activate the commonConstraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(commonConstraints)

        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            // wider than tall, so "landscape"
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(wideConstraints)
        } else {
            // taller than wide
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(narrowConstraints)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
            if size.width > size.height {
                // we're transitioning to wider than tall
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.narrowConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.wideConstraints)
            } else {
                // we're transitioning to taller than wide
                NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(self.wideConstraints)
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.narrowConstraints)
            }
        }, completion: {
            _ in
            // if you want to do somwthing after the transition
        })

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ref:-
Before Update Constraints Check already applied constraint. if already have constraint get them and update others.

Example:-

```
     //Height
        if let heightConstraint = cv1.constraints.first(where: { $0.firstAttribute == .height })
        {
            heightConstraint.constant = safeAreaHeight
        }
        else
        {
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                cv1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: safeAreaHeight)
            ])
        }
        
        //Width
        if let widthConstraint = cv1.constraints.first(where: { $0.firstAttribute == .width })
                  {
                      widthConstraint.constant = safeAreaWidth / 2
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                          cv1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: safeAreaWidth / 2)
                      ])
                  }
```